# How to find the min value of a string data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find out min value of a string in SQL corresponding to the type column in the lease table. The customer and the lease tables have primary / foreign key relationship through the `Customer_Id` column.

The `Lease` table can have three possible rows for a given `CustomerId`. So, for each row in the `Customer` table, the `Lease` table can have a row of `Type = "T"` and `Type = "P"` and `Type = "U"`.

In that case, the query has to return "P" as it's the min of the three possible values between T, U and P. If the Lease table had rows corresponding to only "T" and "U", then the query should return "T".

I am getting, "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'" error.

This is my SQL statement:

```
select  
    Customer_Id, min(lease) as leasetype 
from 
    (values(L1.type), (L2.type), (L3.type)) as T(lease) 
from 
    CUSTOMER c 
join 
    lease L1 on L1.customer_id = c.customer_id and L1.type = 'T' 
join
    lease L2 on L2.customer_id = c.customer_id and L2.type = 'U' 
join
    lease L3 on L3.customer_id = c.customer_id and L3.type = 'P'
where 
    c.order_timestamp >=  '03/01/2018'
```

The following is my table data:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two `FROM` clauses.

Also, I think you can simplify the query a lot...

```
select  
    c.customer_id, min(l.type) as leasetype 
from 
    CUSTOMER c 
join 
    lease l
        on l.customer_id = c.customer_id
where
        l.type IN ('P', 'T', 'U')
    AND c.order_timestamp >=  '03/01/2018'
GROUP BY
    c.customer_id
```

Unless you also need other fields from the `lease` table?  Then use the `ROW_NUMBER()` approach from another answer here.

Answer (score 0):

use row_number()

```
select customer_id, email_address,Amount from
(select c.customer_id,c.email_address,
  L1.Amount,
row_number()over(partition by c.customer_id order by 
  case when Type='P' then 1 when Type='T' then 2 else 3 end ) rn
from 
    CUSTOMER c 
join 
    lease L1 on L1.customer_id = c.customer_id
) a where a.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is to join the customer table to an inline table that selects your min lease.

```
select c.Customer_id, ml.lease
from customer c
inner join (select customer_id, min(lease) from lease) ml 
on c.customer_id = ml.customer_id
where 
    c.order_timestamp >=  '03/01/2018';
```

Answer (score 0):

first thing I see in your query is the syntax of your "as T(lease)"
The "as" keyword is used to make an alias and only one word is needed (I never saw any other writing but correct me if I'm wrong).
I'd try without parenthesis.

Second thing I see is that you have 2 from which is totally forbidden.. If you want to use many tables, I'd advised you to look into the join syntax